# Select lowest and 2nd lowest value in row

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data frame and would like to add 2 additional columns - Lowest and 2nd lowest

If lowest is e.g 22 but 2nd lowest would be 23 then use 22, I would like to have 23 only if there is nothing less than 23.

Can anybody help me with this as i'm stuck here for some time ;/

```py
data = {"A":[22,22,22,19],"B":[23,23,19,17],"C":[22,23,20,15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  A   B   C
0  22  23  22
1  22  23  23
2  22  19  20
3  19  17  15
```

```
Expected Result:
   A   B   C  Lowest  2nd lowest
0  22  23  22      22          22
1  22  23  23      22          22
2  22  19  20      19          20
3  19  17  15      15          17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```
df.iloc[[row_number]].max().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the new dataframe with output you desire

```
lar = lambda x: dict(zip(df.columns.tolist()+['lowest','second_lowest'],x.values.tolist()+x.nsmallest(2).values.tolist()))
df.apply(lar,axis=1,result_type='expand')

In [13]: df.apply(lar,axis=1,result_type='expand')
Out[13]:
    A   B   C  lowest  second_lowest
0  22  23  22      22             22
1  22  23  23      22             23
2  22  19  20      19             20
3  19  17  15      15             17
```

Comment: for Index 1 it should result as 22 in second_lowest

Comment: check the output first. i am not getting why you want it to work that way. there are other values then 23 in the row, how would you validate then, and still if you want that just put a conditional check in the lambda function.